# Korean Subway help please!

Tags: korean-culture, resources

I have an urgent question about the subway
route[image]

From green line, I want to transfer at Sindorim station. From there I want to go to Guil. Now I know the subway travels from Sindorim and then Guro, but I don't know what direction will the subway go from there. Will it go to Guil where I need to go or will it go to Gasan Digital Complex? Is there a way of knowing? Am I going to need to get off at Guro and get on another subway?

I will appreciate any help any of you here can give me! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Go to platform 2, where trains for 병점·천안·신창·인천 stop. Take the train for 인천, which is, in general, every second train.

Comment: Thank you so much @Taegyung

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a it is a question "about Korean culture that do not concern the Korean language itself."

Answer (score 2):

There will be boards at each stop that say which direction a train is going (based on the final destination).  If you are looking to go to Guil, the board will say the train goes to Incheon, as that is the final destination of that route.

Comment: Thank you so much @buratino